# Mutex for every element in a structure array

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, structure, mutex

I want to make every element in an array of structure thread safe by using mutex lock for accessing each element of array.

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct {
  void      *value;
  void      *key;
  uint32_t  value_length;
  uint32_t  key_length;
  uint64_t  access_count;
  void      *next;
  pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
} lruc_item;
```

I have an array of this structure, and want to use mutex locks in order to make structure elements thread safe.

I tried using the lock on one of the array element in a function and then intensionally didn't unlock it, just to ensure that my locks are working fine, but the strange thing was that there was no deadlock and the 2nd function accessing the same array element was able to access it.

Can some one please guide me on how to use mutexes to lock every element in a structure array (so as to make each element of the struture thread safe).

sample code to explain my point:

```
/** FUNCTION THAT CREATES ELEMENTS OF THE STRUCTURE **/

lruc_item *create_item(lruc *cache) {
  lruc_item *item = NULL;

item = (lruc_item *) calloc(sizeof(lruc_item), 1);

item->mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  if(pthread_mutex_init(item->mutex, NULL)) {
    perror("LRU Cache unable to initialise mutex for page");
    return NULL;
     }

  }

 return item;
}


set()
{
item = create_item(cache);

  pthread_mutex_lock(item->mutex);
    item->value = value;
    item->key = key;
    item->value_length = value_length;
    item->key_length = key_length;
    item->access_count = ++cache->access_count;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(item->mutex);     /** (LINE P) tried commenting out this to check  proper working of mutex(deadlock expected if the same "item" is accessed in another function)  **/


}

get(lruc_item *item)
{

  pthread_mutex_lock(item->mutex);   /** deadlock doesn't occur when "LINE P" is commented out**/ 
    *value = item->value;
    item->access_count = ++cache->access_count;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(item->mutex);

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you're using the mutex ?

Comment: Why do you have the `mutex` as a pointer, and not simply as a `pthread_mutex_t` directly? Looks as if you are complicating your life by allocating `*mutex`.

Comment: The premise is flawed, whatever it may look like.  A mutex *blocks code*, it doesn't lock data.

Comment: I have posted some relevent code.

Comment: In debugger, or through print, did you verify that the two items are the same item?

Comment: Can you detail how each call to set/get is made on different threads?  without that, it's impossible to tell if pthread_mutex_lock is working as intended.

Comment: this really begs the question: what problem are you trying to solve? have you found that there's too much contention for a mutex for the data structure as a whole? or is this just a "ZOMG it's GOTS to be faster with more locks!" thinking?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that a mutex only locks out code from other threads.  <s>If you tried to execute `WaitForMultipleObjects` with the same mutex in the same thread it wouldn't block.  I'm assuming Windows, because you haven't detailed that.</s>

But, if you provide more detail, maybe we can pin-point where the issue really is.

<s>Now, assuming again Windows, if you want to make accesses to the *individual elements* "thread-safe", you might want to consider the `InterlockedExchange`-class of functions instead of a mutex.  For example:</s>

```
InterlockExchange(&s.value_length, newValue);
```

or

```
InterlockedExchange64(&s.access_count, new64Value);
```

or

```
InterlockedExchangePointer(&s.value, newPointer);
```

If what you want to do is make sure multiple element accesses to the structure, as a transaction, is thread-safe, then mutex can do that for you.  Mutex is useful across process boundaries.  If you are only dealing within a single process, a critical section might be a better idea.

Comment: Its on linux system and it's a mutex rather than a semaphore, which can allow access to the locked code more than once. Let me include some sample code that would make it clear.

Comment: In that case, ignore all the detail about Windows-specific functions.  The note about a mutex only block code running in other threads is still true; but, if you post code maybe it will be more apparent what the problem is.

Comment: On Linux, a mutex is basically equivalent to a critical section on Windows.  It's small and fast.